# Visual Studio 22 ASP.Net Web Forms: prevent designer from automatically opening the current page when debugging

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2022, designer

When I run my Web Forms application in VS 2022, the designer automatically opens every page I navigate to. So at startup, Site.Master and Login.aspx are automatically opened (the designer displays them in a tab) and VS gains focus. Every effin time I hit one of these pages. Very annoying.

This started a few months back with a VS update. Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't experiance that effect at all, and I'm working on some asp.net + webforms projects all the time in vs2022.

I would however, suggest you check this setting:

tools->options->Web Forms designer.

And then choose this:

[image]

In other words, don't use live preview.

Comment: When I initially changed this setting (without restarting VS), it worked.
Now, after a restart, I experience the same behavior again with the legacy designer.

Comment: In the above screen cap, right below web forms designer, check settings for Web Live Preview.  You want to set "Tools and auto sync enabled to False. I'm using vs2022, and I did not have to mess much, only above use legacy forms designer. I actually can't re-produce your issue.  I guess in Web Live Preview, I would also set CCS Hot reload  enabled to false, and browser link enables to false also. (but, I did not have to change those).